# C# Entity Framework 4.3 DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im working on a MVC application, and was just wondering.. Should I be using the singleton pattern on my dbcontext object or is it safe to just instantiate one in every controller needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a singleton pattern. Use one DbContext for one unit of work. The controller seems like a reasonable place to instantiate the context.